# How to use Clairaut’s Theorem condition in order to minimize the amount of calculations?

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative

According to my textbook:

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/HighOrderPartialDerivs.aspx#Clairaut

*"If the functions $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous (on a disk),  then $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$."*

How is this condition supposed to help? Because to check for the continuity of $f_{xy}$ implies we have to find the derived function first. That is by actually taking the second order partial derivative, first with respect to
$x$ and then $y$.

Then checking for continuity:

$$\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(x_0,y_0\right)}f_{xy}=f_{x_0y_0}$$

Having done that, establishing continuity of $f_{yx}$ would mean to undergo the same process, taking the partial derivatives again, in a different order. And then again plugging the resulting function into a another limit.

What I find the most strange is that it is being used in the following context:
"If we know $f_{xy}$ we don't need to calculate $f_{yx}$ because they are the same (according to Clairaut’s Theorem)".

**TLDR**: The following contradiction seems to arise: If we know $f_{xy}$ we don't have to calculate $f_{yx}$, because they are same. BUT we do have to actually calculate both of them to check if they are continuous functions.

So my question is how to use it practically in order to actually minimize calculations?

Comment: Example: say $A$ is a fixed matrix and let $x\in\mathbb R^2$. Then  $\langle Ax,x\rangle^{100000}$ is a smooth function, because it is a composition of the bilinear map $\langle x,y\rangle$ , the linear function $Ax$, the linear function $x\mapsto (x,x)$ and the (1D) polynomial $t^{100000}$. I have no idea what the second derivatives are without computing, but Clairut guarantees the mixed partials are the same.

Comment: Do you mean to say we can simply assume if f(x,y) is continuous then its second order partial derivatives must also be continuous even without calculation?

Comment: no! absolutely not! that's wrong! but there are other ways to know that a function is $C^2$, beyond direct calculation

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will have to study how smoothness works, there is a lot to learn.